# Angular Reactive Forms - How to iterate through nested FormArray?

Tags: angular

Here is the code example:

```
<div formArrayName="formControl" *ngFor="let item of formArrControl.controls; let i = index">
   <div [formGroupName]="i">
      <div formArrayName="nestedFormControl" *ngFor="let nestedControl of item.get('formControl2').controls; let j = index"> 
          
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So the problem is to get nested control (item.get('formControl2').controls). I keep getting error "Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'". I found solution using a function, so instead of iterate through "item.get('formControl2').controls", I changed it to control(item).

control function code:

```
control(item: AbstractControl) {
    return item.get('formControl2') as FormArray;
}
```

So is this Ok solution or it's not smart to use a function inside ngFor?